# Xcode 7 Simulator - “SpringBoard cannot be opened because of a problm.”

Tags: macos, mac, xcode, ios

I was successfully using the Xcode Simulator yesterday evening. This morning when I came into work, I didn't change anything, but suddenly, every time I open the Simulator, this error pops up "SpringBoard cannot be opened because of a problem." The same exact thing is also happening to 2 other coworkers on their Macs. I've clicked Report and sent a report to Apple.

[image]

Since I didn't touch anything, I can only assume that the problem was caused by some update that happened in the background between last night and this morning. I've tried deleting the simulator devices and adding them back. I've tried clicking "Reset Contents and Settings..." in the Simulator menu. And I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode.

I have:

- **OS X El Capitan 10.11.5**
- **Xcode 7.3.1 (7D1014)**
- **Simulator 9.3 (SimulatorApp-645.9)**

I have no idea why this would suddenly be an issue. Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1):

### **UPDATE 2:** We were able to track it down to an update of security software called Cylance Protect. After uninstalling it, the Simulator worked again.

### **UPDATE:** It just happened again! About a week after reformatting our macs, we're all getting the same issue, at the same time.

My coworker just fixed the problem by getting his mac re-imaged. Looks like the problem required a cannon. I still don't know what caused it, and I'm not confident it won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  While troubleshooting my problem, I had the Springboard error pop up when I attempted to use the iPad Simulator.  With the iPhone Simulator I had the errors listed in the link below.  Either way, the resolution was what I posted in my link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870468/xcode-7-3-wont-attach-to-simulator-to-debug/37625450#37625450

Answer (score -1):

Note: Probably not the answer to your problem but adding as it might be related.

I had this error today when opening 'iOS Simulator' from spotlight.
Then I recalled that 'iOS Simulator' was the name of the old xcode simulator and was replace by 'Simulator' - a seperate and different app.

'Simulator' works fine and as expected.